# Cannot convert "System.String" to "System.Object[,]"

Tags: excel, vb.net

(Working on VS 2017)

I have a range referencing an excel column with 2 (or more) cells.
To get his data, I convert into an Object(,) with this code:

```
somevar = CType(ExcelWorksheet.Range(CeldaLat.Offset(0, 0), LastCell).Value2, Object(,))
```

I get this result:
[image: Link to image]

Note that I get a column with a title and a cell with data.
**CeldaLat** references the first cell of the range, and **LastCell** references the last cell of the data.

```
LastCell = CeldaLat.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
```

I don't want the title, ("latitud" on the first row), so I change the offset() to get only the data with this code:

```
somevar = CType(ExcelWorksheet.Range(CeldaLat.Offset(1, 0), LastCell).Value2, Object(,))
```

I works perfectly when I have more than 1 row of data (the range is larger than 2 rows), but in the case shown on the former image, (2 rows range, with 1 data cell), I get this error:

[image: quick watch]

The error is "Cannot convert "System.String" to "System.Object[,]"
[image: error]

Apparently, when a single cell is left in the range, it cannot be converted to an array of object, **Object(,)**, (becasue is not array?)

[image: object(string) is not an array?]

There is a single line of code working for all cases? Or I need to make a function checking the lenght of the range to convert it to object(,)?

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed I need to use CType because is on Option Explicit. The problem is that I need to cast it on an array, and a single cell range apparently cannot be cast into an array.

Comment: My bad, `.Value2` returns an object of type `Object`, not `Object(,)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently, when a single cell is left in the range, it cannot be converted to an array of object.

Correct. `Value` of a single cell is a single value, `Value` of a multicell range is a 2D array.

If you want an array in all cases, either check the number of cells in the range before calling `Value`, or call `Value` and see if it is an array or not - for which you need to remember that everything is an `Object`:

```
Dim somevar As Object = ExcelWorksheet.Range(CeldaLat.Offset(0, 0), LastCell).Value2
Dim result As Object(,)

If IsArray(somevar) Then
    result = DirectCast(somevar, Object(,))
Else
    result = New Object(,) {{somevar}}
End If
```